# Which built-in DistanceFunction options does Mathematica offer?

Tags: functions, function-construction, machine-learning

The documentation is not specific at all about which **built-in** distance functions are implemented in Mathematica:

> https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceFunction.html

For instance, I know that `EuclideanDistance`, `ChessboardDistance` and `DiceDissimilarity` are some examples. Is there a way to find out all possible **built-in**  distance functions one can use and their internal definition?

Comment: See the guide page ["Distance and Similarity Measures"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DistanceAndSimilarityMeasures.html). (Voting to close.)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I've edited the question to emphasize the "built-in" functionality aspect.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for the link! Why close? Instead I suggest that you post this reference as an answer, and I'll happily accept. Surely, I'm not the only one who is going to be looking for this information in the future, considering the scarcity of the immediate Mathematica documentation on the matter.

Comment: @Kagaratsch "Why close? Instead I suggest that you post this reference as an answer [...]" -- [The guide page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DistanceAndSimilarityMeasures.html) link I posted is at the bottom of the function page of [DistanceFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistanceFunction.html) you refer to in your question. I find it trivial to find that guide and that guide answers your questions/concerns.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I see! You are right, I did not notice that. I'll delete this question later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see a list of functions having names ending with "Distance":

```
 ?"*Distance"
```

[image: result]